# Exploit an XSS when injected Javascript code is returned capitalized

Tags: javascript, security, xss

I have found an XSS vulnerability in a piece of code, as I'm able to inject Javascript code in it.

I want to generate the simple `alert` PoC, but I'm not able to do so as the JS code returned by the server is always capitalized. For example, when I inject the following code:

```
Text sample <script>alert(document.cookie)</script>
```

The server respond with the page containing the following:

```
Text sample <script>ALERT(DOCUMENT.COOKIE)</script>
```

Which obviously does not print the cookie as JS is case sensitive.

Is there a way to transform the code injected in lowercase before it gets rendered or a similar solution?

**Note**: Javascript is enabled and if I modify manually the code in the browser console transforming it in lowercase, I'm getting the cookie printed.

Comment: Sounds like a server config issue. There is no way to validate script  element text using client side code before it gets compiled

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not have control over the transformation and you cannot somehow change it back to lowercase before execution.

However, you *can* inject JavaScript code which is not affected by the capitalisation of the characters. See [jsfuck](http://www.jsfuck.com), which doesn't need alphanumeric source characters at all, and use a similar approach (you can actually use digits and some characters).